# Automatically removing added prefixes (SUM_, MEAN_, FIRST_, ect) from output of arcpy.Statistics_analysis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, fields-attributes

This code is basically run to remove the extra prefixes created by the statistics_analysis module with arcpy, which was performed to find out the totals from aggregated polygons that intersected with another feature layer. I'd like to keep the original field names without adding the prefixes so that the output feature classes work with other models that rely on specific field names.
What am I doing wrong here? It's no longer trying to access required fields, I took care of that with the pops. The code is duplicated because it's looking at two sides of a line.

```
File "PATH\Model_Project_2\Intersect.py", line 218, in <module>
    arcpy.AlterField_management(AggEN2,sw,f)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3239, in AlterField
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 001600: Failed to alter field name.
Failed to execute (AlterField).


Failed to execute (IHAT).
```

---

```
countz = 0
EBflds = [z.name for z in arcpy.ListFields(AggEN2)]
EBflds2 = [w.replace("MEAN_", "") for w in EBflds]
EBflds3 = [w.replace("FIRST_", "") for w in EBflds2]
EBflds4 = [w.replace("SUM_", "") for w in EBflds3]
EBflds4.pop(1)
EBflds4.pop(0)
EBflds4.pop(6)
EBflds4.pop(5)
sizE = len(EBflds4)
EBflds4.pop(sizE-1)
EBflds4.pop(sizE-2)
for z in EBflds4:
    glb = [w.name for w in arcpy.ListFields(AggEN2)]
    glb.pop(1)
    glb.pop(0)
    glb.pop(6)
    glb.pop(5)
    sizEG = len(glb)
    glb.pop(sizEG-1)
    glb.pop(sizEG-2)
    w = glb[countz]
    countz = countz + 1
    arcpy.AlterField_management(AggEN2,w,z)


countz = 0
WBflds = [z.name for z in arcpy.ListFields(AggWS2)]
WBflds2 = [w.replace("MEAN_", "") for w in WBflds]
WBflds3 = [w.replace("FIRST_", "") for w in WBflds2]
WBflds4 = [w.replace("SUM_", "") for w in WBflds3]
WBflds4.pop(1)
WBflds4.pop(0)
WBflds4.pop(6)
WBflds4.pop(5)
sizW = len(WBflds4)
WBflds4.pop(sizW-1)
WBflds4.pop(sizW-2)
for z in WBflds4:
    glb = [w.name for w in arcpy.ListFields(AggWS2)]
    glb.pop(1)
    glb.pop(0)
    glb.pop(6)
    glb.pop(5)
    sizWG = len(glb)
    glb.pop(sizWG-1)
    glb.pop(sizWG-2)
    w = glb[countz]
    sw = str(w)
    countz = countz + 1
    arcpy.AlterField_management(AggWS2,w,z)
```

Comment: Is your file a shapefile or geodatabase feature class? Shapefiles will accept numbers as leading characters as field names while feature classes will not.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is remove the `SUM_`, `FIRST_` and `MAX_` prefixes for all of the fields except for the required fields (which shouldn't contain any of these prefixes anyway), the 3 lines of code below will work just fine, provided there's no duplicate in the resulting field names (e.g. if you try to rename `MEAN_FIELD1` and `SUM_FIELD1` into `FIELD1`):

```
for f in arcpy.ListFields(AggEN2):
    if not f.required:        # not really necessary here, as explained above
        arcpy.AlterField_management(AggEN2, f.name, f.name.replace("SUM_", "").replace("MEAN_", "").replace("FIRST_", ""))
```

Beware that you can't rename fields in shapefiles and dbf tables, either with Alter Field or with another method (you would need to create a copy of the dataset).